# AWS add authentication layer on top of existing website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two AWS ec2 instances, one for production, one for development, both run perfectly fine.

each has its own domain with all necessary configs (certbox, nginx, etc) so the development instance can simulate the production with mock data, also to catch any edge/visual problems that only exists on production.

For example,
`www.example.com` and `development.example.com`.

The problem is that currently both websites are accessible from public. I know `robot.txt` file can hide the dev website from search engine.

But I wonder it's there any possible configs I can do to add a layer of simple user/password on top of the entire dev website via AWS or inside the instance.

I just want to make sure the dev website wouldn't appear together with the production to confuse user.
Any links from AWS are appreciated, I just cannot construct the correct phrases to find the documentation.

Comment: You may want to look at [HTTP basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) which is one of the simplest options. You can do this with [NGINX](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/) and other web servers.

Comment: @jarmod thx, let to check it out to see if it's a quick/viable option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the link from @jarmod.

I quickly set the authentication up via nginx.

It "shallow bans" my testing website from SEO via simple login.

**Note: my intent is not for security purpose.**

The below link has all the details how to create authentication with nginx on ubuntu.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-10

I just **quote** fewer critical lines in case if the link is dead in the future.
**All credits belong to DO.**

Step 1: Apache Utils
We need htpasswd to create and generate an encrypted for the user using Basic Authentication. Install apache2-utils using the command below.

```
  sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
```

Step 2: Create User and Password
Create a .htpasswd file under your website directory being served by nginx. The following command would create the file and also add the user and an encrypted password to it.

```
  sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd exampleuser
```

Step 3: Update Nginx configuration
Your nginx configuration file for the website should be under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`. Add the two entries below under for the domain path that you want to secure.

```
auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
```

The second line is the location of the htpasswd file for your website.

```
 server {
  listen       portnumber;
  server_name  ip_address;
  location / {
      root   /var/www/mywebsite.com;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      auth_basic "Restricted";                                #For Basic Auth
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;  #For Basic Auth
  }
}
```

Step 4: Reload Nginx

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```